# How to format characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting this:

> The job that I&#8217 ;ve spent the last year learning is not the one I&#8217 ;ll have

what should I do to format it with JavaScript or is there any Angular way?

this is a paragraph/post I am getting from a WordPress account.

```
<h2>{{:: post.title}}</h2>

.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, FreshlyPressed) {
  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    $scope.posts = FreshlyPressed.getBlogs($scope);
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
  }
  $scope.doRefresh();
});

.service('FreshlyPressed', function($http) {
  return {
    getBlogs: function($scope) {
      $scope.posts = [];
      $http.jsonp('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/freshly-pressed?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .success(function(result) {
          $scope.posts = result.posts;
        });
    },

    get: function(postId, $scope) {
      console.log(postId);
      console.log($scope.posts);
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.posts.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.posts[i].id === parseInt(postId)) {
          return $scope.posts[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald sorry, watch it again

Comment: "getting this" how? Where? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Where are you "*[getting]*" it from? I'd suggest adjusting the back-end - assuming there is one - to solve this.

Comment: @Pointy sorry, see my update.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer is that what you are looking for below, or have I missed your point. Have just seen with the updated code

Comment: why can't you use it as it is using `ng-bind-html`?

Comment: @charlietfl just can not use stuff like **I've** because all those weird characters comes up. So I need to remove/format those characters.

Comment: those are html entities...did you try `ng-bind-html`?

Comment: @charlietfl bah, that just fix my issue, thank you. Post it as an answer, maybe someone else need it sometime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have are valid html entities that won't work well in angular expressions which use text but should work fine using `ng-bind-html`.

Alternatively you could look for an htmlentities conversion library